# If statement shorthand into and String

Tags: javascript

Hi I wanna know how to write this in Javascript :

```
var object {

    baseUrl: "js" <?php if (DEBUG_MODE) echo '/raw'; ?>"

}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Where will you get the "DEBUG_MODE" value from? Otherwise, `var object = { baseUrl: "js" + (DEBUG_MODE ? '/raw' : '') };`

Comment: I think you needed to supply much more information about what you wanted and expected from the answer

Comment: can you be a little more clear? I agree with adarshr, this looks already like js built on the fly using php

Comment: @Jimmy Well, I disagree... this is half-`JS` half-`PHP`, so we can just guess the actual semantics. But well, my guess is down, so @socrateisabot could explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var object = {
    baseUrl: "js" + ((DEBUG_MODE) ? '/raw' : '')
}
```

Note the added `+` and `=`. Also, this works supposing there is a `DEBUG_MODE` defined somewhere and also supposing I understood what you actually wanted.

EDIT:

In PHP, you were just outputting HTML, so you can output `"js"` and then in `<?php ?>` block output `DEBUG_MODE` and it gets concantenated. In JS, however, you're dealing with two strings, as language objects, hence the `+` to concantenate them.

The `=` should be quite self-explanatory. You **declare** a variable `object` (and you were lucky to use lowercase and not colide with the pre-built `Object`), then **assign** it (`=`) a value - the object literal marked by `{}`.

Comment: @Adnan: Heeey! I really meant the `=` missing before the `{`.

Comment: Great, and what can we learn from this? We learn that it's a good idea to explain the things we put in the answer. For example, you can tell the OP that the `+` does blah blah and `=` does blah blah :)

Comment: @Adnan Satisfied? :-p I agree with you and I usually write long answers. But with this type of question I wanted to wait for OP's reaction first.

Comment: Daamn! You deserve +1 for the kindness and effort.